# Dotnetbrowser DOMElement.NodeValue no effect , no arg's namecan be seen?

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I used latest version dotnetbrowser，
q1:I found the  prop of DOMElement class can not been seen in the debug window, and some class(method)'s arg name can not be seen, this is caused by Confusion protection maybe...

q2: docment.getelementbyid('search').value = 123;this js work ok, 
but  the DOMElement.NodeValue =123 has no any effect on page,is there anything I got wrong?..

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are the answers to your questions.

1. As stated in the [documentation article](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000117030--the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run-message-in-debugger-or-quick-watch),  DotNetBrowser library uses multiple threads for exchanging data between the Chromium engine and .NET. This is also true for the values of the various `DOMElement` properties — that's why you cannot see them directly in the debugger window. In addition, the protection hides the internal logic from the debugger, that's why some information may appear missing in it.
2. The `DOMElement.NodeValue` property corresponds to the [nodeValue](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodevalue.asp) DOM property, not the `value` property of the DOM element. In your case, it is necessary to cast `DOMElement` to `DOMInputElement` and use the `Value` property, which corresponds to the `value` JavaScript property.

Here is a link to the article that demonstrates how to set the input field value:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110038-setting-input-field-value-working-with-form

Comment: thank you , can you add more methods on `DOMDocument`,like `querySelector`and so on

Comment: You can use `DOMDocument.DocumentElement`, which corresponds to the [document.documentElement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_documentelement.asp) in JS and the `<html>` element.